# How to tell MySQL to ignore all indexes for a given query?

Tags: mysql, index, benchmark

I've been benchmarking several queries and learning about indexes by using the [explain function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html), [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profile.html) and the [SQL_NO_CACHE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883720/1132838) option.

My usual benchmarking session goes something like this:

```
SET PROFILING=1;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE xxx;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

Some times after adding indexes, I want to know how the query would perform without any index optimization; so my options so far are to either delete the related indexes or use explain to check what indexes are in use and [hint MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) what indexes to ignore;

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE xxx;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE IGNORE INDEX (field_a) field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE xxx;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

Is there a similar option to tell MySQL not to use any index so I can get the query duration without any index optimization. Something like this:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_NO_INDEXES field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE xxx;
```

Answer (score 2):

After a table name add USE INDEX() without arguments. That will make MySQL to ignore all index in the table.

Example:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table USE INDEX() WHERE xxx;
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

`... FROM tbl IGNORE INDEX (idx1, idx2, ...) ...`

Unfortunately, you need to know the names of all the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you could change the WHERE clause for the sake of the benchmark, do one of two things:

## OPTION #1 : Table Scan

```
SET PROFILING=1;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

## OPTION #2 : Change `WHERE xxx` to WHERE `1=1`

```
SET PROFILING=1;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE 1=1;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE 1=1;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE 1=1;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

This option might be slightly slower.

Comment: Rolando, thanks for the reply but I am not sure if I understand your options. My goal is to know how the same query would perform without indexes. Wouldn't changing the query in any way void the benchmark?

Comment: I don't think `WHERE 1=1` will turn off an index.  (It could be used to fool the Query cache, but `SQL_NO_CACHE` is taking care of that.)

Comment: @RickJames For InnoDB, you are right in that aspect. The query should do a full pass through the PrimaryKey/Clustered Index anyway, even with my OPTION #1. Your approach should be the same, just more work sculpting the index names into the SELECT using information_schema.